# Как соединить с exe сторонние библиотеки?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Как соединить с .exe (Консольное приложение) сторонние библиотеки (DLL)? При компиляции создается .exe и 2 DLL, без которых он не работает. Как можно сделать так, чтобы они были внутри него и остался только exe файл? (Проект в Visual Studio 2019)

Comment: сделать статическую линковку?

Comment: @KoVadim можешь подсказать как?

Comment: @KoVadim Но если речь о сторонней библиотеке - то такая возможность, вообще говоря, есть не всегда?

Comment: в некоторых случаях, можно просто сбросить все файлы в один солюшн и, возможно, все заработает.